# This build is created for production (App Store) and can't be distributed to testers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, testflight

I am trying to upload my apps using testflight. I created apps using Xcode. After I archived my iOS project I upload it using testflight. But the upload was not done and here is error message. "This build is created for production (App Store) and can't be distributed to testers"

I dont know how to solve this please help thanks.
[Test Flight Error Message Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLlCx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test your application for final distribution, you can achieve it with TestFlight like @Amit explained.

More precisely :

- Use **Production Certificate**
- **Archive** your App
- From the **Organizer** (Window tab -> Organizer) you can see all your builds archived.
- Then you can export the one you want to test, pick the **AppStore** **Deployment** option.
- Finally you have to use **Application Loader** (Xcode tab -> Developer Tool).

It will upload your archive, the ipa file on **iTunesConnect**.

From there, your newly uploaded build is available for testing.
You will receive an email and notification from **TestFlight**.

Comment: thanks.. I am having issue last time because I am using TestFlight app to upload .ipa instead of application loader. but this time I used application loader to upload my ipa and changed my app version then it works.

Comment: Accept answer if it helped you. I'm glad to hear that you made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Application Loader to submit app to iTunes also for testFlight test.

see below Link for reference

https://help.como.com/hc/en-us/articles/201574452-Upload-Your-App-to-iTunes-Connect-using-the-Application-Loader //for how to use application loader

for testFlight reference check below link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html

Comment: Sorry I need to upload my app using TestFlight because I need this for testing only before uploading it using Application Loader for final distribution.

Comment: You can also upload build for testing (testFlight)  from Application loader.